# Testing on change event input box in Angular

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, testing, frontend

I am trying to test a method that is triggered when you type in an input box. How do I trigger the change event and pass a value to the input? Say for example I just want to test is onAmountChange called when the input is changed.

Here is the HTML:

```html
          <input
            (change)="onAmountChange()"
            formControlName="expenseAmount"
            id="expenseAmount"
            type="text"
          />
```

Comment: Selenium's a good way to go... it allows you to mimic a user's actions.